# What is the order topology on a finite linearly ordered set?

Tags: general-topology

I tried to solve that but was lost. How can i find the order topology of a finite linearly ordered topology?

Comment: Do you know what is meant by the "order topology" induced by a linear order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order topology on any linearly ordered set is always $T_1$, because the closed interval $[x, x] $ is closed for all $x$. But a finite $T_1$ space is discrete.

Comment: $T_1$ is the symbol of which space?

Comment: A $T_1$ space is a space where points are closed.

Comment: Alternatively, $\{y: y < x\}$ and $\{y ; y > x\}$ are subbasic open in the order topology, and so $\{x\}$, the complement of their union, is closed. And so all subsets of a finite space are closed etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any finite ordered set is well-ordered, hence a finite ordinal, i.e. homeomorphic to a set of the form $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, so discrete.